# Display registered person values to another html page in django

Tags: python, html, django

I have member table for registration.I want to display that table values(like firstname,lastname, email etc...) in another page (only registered person values )

I tried with id. if I give id means only that particular value is displaying but I want to registered person values

This is my member table

```
class Member(models.Model):
   firstname=models.CharField(max_length=30)
   lastname=models.CharField(max_length=30)
   Email=models.CharField(max_length=50)
   password=models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: how do you detect which one has registered which one is not?

Comment: Please provide in detail what you have tried and what is not working according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a user field so that you can get the data of a logged in user

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    firstname=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lastname=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Email=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

In your view to get the logged-in user data, you can use `request.user`

```
member = Member.objects.get(user=request.user)
print(member.firstname)
```

Comment: we don't want manual use of id. we want an page were the data should be retrieved automatically

without giving id keys

Comment: instead of using id you can use other fields like the firstname lastname and etc that you specified in you model.Just use .get()

Comment: ohh you want to display all the data?

Comment: i want some of the data to get displayed in the profile page of the person who is logged in.

Comment: ok, I have updated my answer. is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

you are talking about a registered person in your app but there is no field in your models to note which one is registered! so First, you should make a decision about your members' login method and keep some data about them. one simple way is to make another table to save registered members, like this, may be useful.

```
class RegisteredMember(models.Model):
     Member = model.ForeignKey(Member,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     #and other data you need to save
```

So now you can manage your registered members and find them and get data about them all things you need to do.